# Is the "concept of time" coded into the genome?

Tags: genomes

What I'm interested about is whether environmental changes' effects are coded into the genome, like metamorphosis, deciduous plants. Can it be explained by morphogens, or it's something completely different?

Comment: I tried to narrow it a bit. I'm sorry, if I was not successful enough.

Comment: Do you know about epigenetic?

Comment: Something you might be interested in is circadian clocks, which are literally genetically encoded timekeeping devices. Although they can be entrained by environment, they can also "free run" in constant conditions cycling in the absence of light/dark cues. The core circadian clock in photosynthesizing bacteria called cyanobacteria consists of just three proteins. You can isolate them from the rest of the cell, and just like a watch taken from your wrist, these proteins will continue to oscillate in a 24-hour cycle. If that isn't a genetically encoded "concept of time," I don't know what is!